# how should I spy on a constructor that is called inside of another object?

Tags: node.js, testing, coffeescript, sinon

Let's say I have an object that has a function that creates another object as part of its operation.

```
sinon = require('sinon')
chai = require 'chai'
sinonChai = require("sinon-chai")
chai.use(sinonChai)
chai.should()
Paper = {}
Paper.Origami = require('../assets/src/coffee/origami.coffee').Paper.Origami

describe '#throwOrigami', ->
  it 'should create origami and throw it', ->
    m = new Monkey()
    throwSpy = sinon.spy(m, 'throwOrigami') 
    createSpy = sinon.spy(Paper, 'Origami')     
    # next function creates origami, then 'throws' it at someone
    m.throwOrigami(); 
    createSpy.should.have.been.calledWithNew
    throwSpy.should.have.been.calledOnce
```

The Monkey class has a require at the top for `Paper.Origami`.

I can get this test to pass if I create an Origami inside the test, but it won't pass if I leave it to the create inside of the Monkey object. I suspect this is because the require paths differ between the two objects -- maybe node doesn't see them as the same object.

Question: can I get the `sinon` spy to spy on the creation of the `Origami` object that happens inside the `Monkey` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` resolves paths before looking in its cache, so it should not matter that the paths are different. However, you create a new `Paper` object with an `Origami` property in your test. Hence, when you spy on `Paper, 'Origami'`, it is the property `Origami` of the `Paper` object you created locally in your test file which is replaced with a spy. I suppose you could do the following instead:

```
Paper = require('../assets/src/coffee/origami.coffee').Paper
```

If you now alter the `Paper` object, it would be the same as used in your `Monkey` module. However, I would suggest using something like [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to spy or mock on dependencies.